# settings values of viewDidLoad from XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I am writing unit test cases for a project of mine and having many issues as this is first time I am writing test cases. My app is a typical login and then navigationcontroller based application. 
I am writing test case for a viewcontroller where I am setting some values in viewdidload. These values are fetched from NSUserdefaults and from previous viewcontroller. I have created object of viewcontroller in setup() method of xunit as following:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AlertDetailsViewController") as! AlertDetailsViewController
```

Now when I run setup there is a crash as there is no object which should have received by this class before loading. Is there a way by which I can set values for my viewcontroller before loading of viewdidLoad()?
Also how should I test it for nsuserdefaults. I need to save/retrieve values from nsuserdefault. Is there a way to mock it?

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I know It is late reply..but This is for new viewers...

```
var alertdetailViewController: UIViewController?
weak var alertDetailViewControllerObj: AlertDetailsViewController?

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    alertdetailViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "AlertDetailsViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlertDetailsViewController")

    ashTestResultViewControllerObj = alertdetailViewController as? AlertDetailsViewController
```

}

```
    XCTAssertNotNil(alertdetailViewController?.viewDidLoad())
```

viewDidLoad of alertdetailViewController will be start executed.You can put break points and debug your viewdidload method.
If any objects is not initialized in your Viewcontroller'viewDidLoad method, then you can expect crash.There is no way you can handle this.